# Android: MediaRecorder setPreferredDevice is not working

Tags: android, record

I'm trying to configure the input device for android audio recorder application, from the list of external connected input devices (external mic, headphones, earbuds) I want to choose external mic to do the recording, so I'm using this code

```
AudioDeviceInfo externalMicDeviceInfo = get...;
final success = mediaRecorder.setPreferredDevice(externalMicDeviceInfo);
// success = true
```

The problem is that setPreferredDevice is returning "success = true" but the external mic is not selected as a recording device, because actually the recording is done by the headphones.